# Can you print text in colors other than blue using a print command in python 3.2?

Tags: python-3.x, text, printing, colors, color-scheme

My code currently only prints text in blue but I would like some important messages to be printed using the print() command but in colors such as red.

I tried using something called colorama which I found in a different question's answer.

```
    import colorama
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

    colorama.init()

    print(Fore.RED+'Hello')
```

But it came up with this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:/Color test", line 1, in <module>
            import colorama
    ImportError: No module named colorama
```

Does anyone know how to do it or at least know if it is possible?

EDIT: I have found a similar question and tried all of the answers but none of them worked. I will really appreciate anybody's help.

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167465/how-to-print-colorful-text-in-python-terminal?rq=1

Comment: I couldn't find what i was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ANSI escape codes.

```py
    Black: \u001b[30m
    Red: \u001b[31m
    Green: \u001b[32m
    Yellow: \u001b[33m
    Blue: \u001b[34m
    Magenta: \u001b[35m
    Cyan: \u001b[36m
    White: \u001b[37m
    Reset: \u001b[0m
```

Suppose you want to print "Hello world" in blue, You will have to do:

```py
print("\u001b[34m" + "Hello world" + "\u001b[0m")
```

Please note that I have added the reset code at the end to avoid coloring the rest of the text.

Additionally, if you are using a windows operating system you will need to clear the screen for the colors to appear, like this:

```py
import os
os.system("cls")
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

There is a way - but that it is much more difficult than what I can just simply put in here and is a lot more advanced. [is it possible to add colors to python output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863812/is-it-possible-to-add-colors-to-python-output/20863909#20863909) Go to that weblink for more info.

Comment: This statement is false. It is quite possible to print in colour in a console that supports for example ANSI colour codes. It turned out in a side channel conversation that OP is using IDLE, and as such cannot indeed print in colour according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863812/is-it-possible-to-add-colors-to-python-output/20863909#20863909).

Comment: While this is true - what I stated still stands that mine is a little more user-friendly with actually commands to use.@llja Everilla, that method is long and you spend more time reading than actually writing code. I don't want to start an argue-ment - but both methods do work, just that mine is less reading and more practical. Why would you go through the effort to write a one-line coloured text when Tkinter can do multiple in just 3 to 4 lines less.

Comment: Might be right there... I dont know... just let him decide which way is best